# netbeans - how to view file full path in window title (or somewhere else)?

Tags: netbeans

I've just switched from eclipse, and what bothers me, is that when I have lots of files open, I don't see which one is from which module (f.ex. 5 different urls.py files). Is there an option to show the full path somewhere?

netbeans 6.7.1 @ ubuntu 9.10

//edit:

if not displaying the filename, maybe jumping to the file on the actual view (file view)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't know of an option to show the full path in the tab or window, but I handle this problem in several ways:

- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> while in the editor to highlight the file in the Projects View
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> Show the file in the Files (actual folders) View.
- Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to open files by name (which shows the path and the project)

Hopefully you can use one of these to your advantage.

Comment: both are totally inefficient for me. switching the view to the messy project one feels more confusing than manually looking up files. if there's no solution, i hear eclipse knocking on my door. thanks for the ideas though.

Comment: I edited my answer to give you the option to show Files view.

Comment: tx. i accept your anwer, while i got back to eclipse and it's a huge relief. netbeans doens't even provide good code completion for my django apps, and using it feels like wiping butt with glass.

Answer (score 11):

I know this question is old, but for other folks, who Google here like me: There is a plugin called "show-path-in-title". You can download it directly from Netbeans, or here: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/42000/show-path-in-title

Comment: Really? / Sadly after work with ST2" I can't go back to a so sloow IDE

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is incredible that a so little issue can discourage so much.

===

> Another way is maintain open the
>   "properties" window: Ctrl+Shift+7
>   Shows name, size, modification time...

You can have that window undocked, even in another screen, if you have it. Always is on top. So, wow, is something just discovered. And seems a very cool solution!!!
THX!!!

Answer (score 5):

The [Show Path in Titlebar](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/42000/show-path-in-title) plugin is useful if you have a titlebar, which I personally consider a useless feature and disable. Luckily in **Netbeans 8.0.2** you have a number of other options.

- you can enable showing full file path below the tab:

[image: show full file path]

- you can enable showing parent directory on the tab itself:

[image: show parent folder name in tab title]

- kind of related, there is a plugin called [Cool Editor Actions](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/39634/cool-editor-actions) that allows you to see all the parent folders all the way to the root amongst other features:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you hover your mouse over the tab with the file name, it will pop-up the full path.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715241/netbeans-easy-way-to-tell-which-netbeans-project-a-file-belongs-to/21934637#21934637) shall usher in more productivity and effeciency in your workflow. It allows you to see the path of the file open in the tab.